# Assigning array to std::vector gives incorrect output

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int p[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
vector<int> x(p[0], p[4]);

class Polynomial {    
};

int main(){
    Polynomial Poly;

    unsigned int i;

    for(i = 0;i<=4; i++)
        cout<< x[i]<<endl;

    return 0;


}
```

The above code outputs:

> 5
>   -1073741824
>   0
>   -1073741824
>   -2018993448

Whereas I expect it to output

> 1
>   2
>   3
>   4
>   5

Why is the output incorrect, and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @KerrekSB: Hmm, that sounds like something one can get a brown badge for.

Comment: @OP -- FYI, using `at()` instead of `[ ]` to access your items in the loop shows that the output doesn't even get to the second element before throwing an exception, [as seen here](http://ideone.com/sdJ5ZS).

Comment: shit my bad lol im new to this

Answer (score 3):

The access `x[i]` is out of bounds when `i` is greater than 0, since `x` is a vector containing one (= `p[0]`) element of value 5 (= `p[4]`).

This is because [`vector<int> v(a, b)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) creates a vector with `a` elements with value `b` each.

To achieve what you want (`x` being the same as `p`), you need:

```
#include <iterator>

vector<int> x(std::begin(p), std::end(p))
```

Or, guessing the size yourself:

```
vector<int> x(p, p + 5);
```

Or perhaps somewhat C-like:

```
vector<int> x(p, p + sizeof(p)/sizeof *p);
```

Comment: @SuzanneElm: No problem. I added solutions to what I think you meant to do.

Answer (score 1):

`vector<int> x(p[0], p[4]);` doesn't do what you expect. It constructs a `vector` with `p[0]` elements of value `p[4]`.

This overload of [std::vector::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) will be called here.

```
explicit vector( size_type count,
                 const T& value,
                 const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

If you try `cout << x.size();` you'll find the size of `vector` is `1`, `cout << x[i]` when `i > 0` is out of bound and leads to UB.

You might want to call this overload:

```
template< class InputIt >
vector( InputIt first, InputIt last,
        const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

Then change it to `vector<int> x(&p[0], &p[4]);`. Note this will constructor `vector` with `4` elements. `vector<int> x(&p[0], &p[5]);` will constructor `vector` with all the `5` elements from `p`.